# Laravel IDE helper

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

I was wondering why putting the `_ide_helper.php` is supposed to go to `.gitignore` file?

Majority of my team uses PHPStorm and even if they didn't, would the file do them any "harm" actually?

Comment: `_ide_helper.php` is not just for PHPStorm, other IDEs like e.g. NetBeans make use of it as well. In fact PhpStorm has plugins that might make the ide helper a bit reduntant. I do commit it personally but it is optional.

Comment: *"I was wondering why putting the _ide_helper.php is supposed to go to .gitignore file?"* Because it's not actually the code you need (require) to run or develop your project; it's just for IDE to offer a better code completion. But then, that is completely up to you and your team. If you want to include it and you are in a team, I would suggest to keep such IDE-only files in separate folder (so they can be easily ignored/excluded by those who do not need it)

Comment: Conventionally, ide-specific files should be in .gitignore, but this one is actually pretty useful, so I'd keep it in the repo.  I can confirm that PHPStorm's plugins are definitely not enough to make this file redundant.  In fact even this file isn't enough to fully unravel the maze of indirections that is laravel's source, but it at least helps.

Answer (score 1):

No harm. Unless some brilliant fellow decides to use it inside your application to do something creative, you may commit it.

Since it's only going to be used by your ide, no harm will come from it. You can think of it like the .gitignore file or the composer require-dev section.

What I'd suggest you do instead, is install the Laravel plugin available to PHPStorm, which provides autocomplete to facades and even keys while using the config function. Pretty neat!